# How to set a relative path to a SQL Server Compact database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

How do I write the path to a compact database so it will work for everyone working on the project?

My local path looks something like this:

```
SqlCeConnection con = 
    new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Unwanted\Local\Path\App_Data\Databas.sdf");
```

I think I've seen people use "~" sign to do stuff like this, anyhow I want to make this connection viable for everyone no matter how their mapping looks like.

Hope I made myself clear! :)

Answer (score 4):

The tilde (`~`) is used in **ASP.NET** to denote the root of the web site - it cannot however be used in a SQL Server CE connection string.

You can try to just use

```
SqlCeConnection con = 
    new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=App_Data\Database.sdf");
```

Then the .NET app will look into the current directory (from where it's been started - often the `(project dir)\bin\debug` folder) for a `App_Data` folder and for a `Database.sdf` file inside that folder.

Comment: Hmm, this method seemed to work but it doesen't, dont you need an absolute path for an SqlCE connection?

Comment: [According to this web site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce) - no, doesn't seem to be a requirement. Relative paths should work just fine ...