# Database connection from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I have a folder 'Data' in my WPF application in which there is an .sdf database file.
This file is the database for my application.

When developing my app I used a fixed path to my db like this:

```
'Data Source=P:\Dropbox\Projects\MembersApp\MembersApp\bin\Debug\Data\RF_db.sdf'
```

Now I want to use the |DataDirectory| value so that the app always can find the db, were ever the app is installed. I found this solution on StackOverflow:

```
string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
string dataSourceHome = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\RF_db.sdf";
```

But is giving me an error on the last line 'Bad compile constant value'. I've tried with:

```
string dataSourceHome = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\RF_db.sdf";
```

But that doesn't work.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I found this solution here [StackOverflow][1] which works for me.
Just needed to rename my 'Data' folder to 'App_Data' and use this code:

      string data = @"Data Source=App_Data\RF_db.sdf";
      LocalConnection = new SqlCeConnection(data);

This works for me when I run my app localy. However when I deploy my app with clickonce it fails.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932963/how-to-set-a-relative-path-to-a-sql-server-compact-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change `DataDirectory` in your code; it is set by the installer and changing it will prevent your app from knowing where the data was installed. Just use:

```
string dataSourceHome = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\RF_db.sdf";
```

And nothing else. Do not call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path)`; that's what is breaking things.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
string dataSourceHome = string.Format("Data Source={0}\\RF_db.sdf", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

or

```
 string dataSourceHome = string.Format("Data Source={0}\\RF_db.sdf", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

Comment: If he is using an installer or ClickOnce the data directory may not be the application nor the assembly directory. In fact, from his edit it appears it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your creating a ADO.Net connection string. Isn't there just information missing from your `dataSourceHome`?
Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented).

Or a different approach to creating the connection might be found on [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce).